# JSON convert into string in python

Tags: python, json

```
s= {'total_time': 39.420217514038086, 'fingerprint_time': 17.634710550308228, 'query_time': 12.381393909454346, 'align_time': 8.720932483673096, 'results': [{'song_id': 8, 'song_name':'Naio, Mr Music Man', 'input_total_hashes': 134302, 'fingerprinted_hashes_in_db': 134302, 'hashes_matched_in_input': 134302, 'input_confidence': 1.0, 'fingerprinted_confidence': 1.0, 'offset': 0, 'offset_seconds': 0.0, 'file_sha1':'0ED28744EF5238735DBC7F4F1F4FB96D61E07C6A'}, {'song_id': 9, 'song_name':'Naio, King of Kings', 'input_total_hashes': 134302, 'fingerprinted_hashes_in_db': 128063, 'hashes_matched_in_input': 38773, 'input_confidence': 0.29, 'fingerprinted_confidence': 0.3, 'offset': 1392, 'offset_seconds': 64.64435, 'file_sha1':'07B095A1D5CB590D9E308B05A4A7448E458443A0'}]}

data = [str(item) for item in s]
```

how can i convert all the valu ino string with apostrophe above is not working for me. all i want is to put all numbers in apostrophe.

need help

Comment: That is not a json, that is a *dict*

Comment: remove 'b' in front of all values should fixed json format.

Comment: What? No, you don't understand. JSON is a text-based serialization format. If you had JSON, you would be talking about some piece of text. What you have here is *a dictionary*, not JSON

Comment: thanks for pointing out. might as well need help to loop it through just need to get song_name values.

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over a dictionary, by default you are iterating only over keys. You need to use the items() method to get both the key and value. Here for example:

```
data = {key: str(val) for key, val in s.items()}
```

If you strictly want the values as string, then:

```
data = [str(val) for val in s.values()]
```

Comment: thanks iam trying to get song_name 
iam using 
data = re.sub(": b",":", (str(dat)))
to remve 'b' infront of the valus. data looks good but i can't loop it all to get song_name

Comment: @AlfredGeorge  That seems like a different question altogether.